# Derivative of a row vector with respect to a column vector; derivative with respect to a row vector assuming numerator layout.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

Refer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Vector-by-vector 
I see above that, assuming the numerator layout, the derivative of a $(m \times 1)$ column vector $\textbf{y}$ with respect to a $(n \times 1)$ column vector $\textbf{x}$ gives a $(m \times n)$ matrix with $(i,j)$-th element $\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j}$. 
 
Refer: https://youtu.be/WrH-jpJIqFQ?list=PLhcN-s3_Z7-YS6ltpJhjwqvHO1TYDbiZv&t=222 
I see above how it can be obtained by employing the Kronocker product (?)

**1. How is the derivative of a row vector with respect to a column vector defined? How is the resultant matrix obtained - what is its dimension and what will be the $(i,j)$-th element?**

**2. How is the derivative with respect to a row vector defined?**


Background: 
I was going through the identities in

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Vector-by-vector_identities 
   I can understand using above sources that $\frac{\partial A\textbf{x}}{\partial \textbf{x}}=A$. But I can't get $\frac{\partial \textbf{x}^TA}{\partial \textbf{x}}=A^T$
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-vector_identities 
   I can't understand how to take derivative with respect to $x^T$ (a row vector) in $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial x^T} = H^T$

Comment: Try to write explicit indices $(i,j)$ to make sense of these. There are several conventions.

Comment: Notice in the video, they talk about just "vectors", not "column vectors/row vectors". Both row and column vectors are particular cases of vectors. "Column" and "row" are just ways of interpreting the vectors. So the definitions given apply to both column and row vectors.

Comment: @PC1 I tried reverse engineering the identity $\frac{\partial \textbf{x}^TA}{\partial \textbf{x}}=A^T$, I can obtain the result by implicitly treating the row vector $\textbf{x}^TA$ as a column vector(?). But this brings up the query why we need the $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \textbf{x} \partial \textbf{x}^T}$ notation ( which I assumed represented $\frac{\partial}{\partial \textbf{x}}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \textbf{x}})^T$ to ensure derivatives are taken on column vector functions in the numerator layout) is used instead of $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \textbf{x} ^2}$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair But won't the interpretation (row/column) of the vector affect the dimension of the result obtained from the Kronocker product with row vector of derivative operations (as shown in the video). So the derivative of the vector $\textbf{y}$ wrt to a column vector $\textbf{x}_{(n \times 1)}$:
 if $\textbf{y}_{(m\times 1)}$
 is a column vector gives an $m\times n$
 result but if $\textbf{y}_{(1\times m)}$
 is a row vector gives an $1 \times mn$
 result (?)

Comment: That is not a problem with the definition. That is a problem of how you have chosen to interpret the result. Either way, you get the same $mn$ numbers. In one, you (not the definition) have decided to put them in an $m\times n$ array. In the second, you (not the definition) have chosen to put them in a $1 \times mn$ array.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I understand, but this brings me back to my original question on how the dimensions of the result are determined when finding the derivative of a row vector with respect to the column vector. Using the Kronocker product method in the video, I am able to see that $\frac{\partial A\textbf{x}}{\partial \textbf{x}}=A$ is consistent, but when I apply the same to $\frac{\partial \textbf{x}^TA}{\partial \textbf{x}}$, I get a row vector with $m \times n$ elements instead of $A^T$ as shown in the wikipedia vector-by-vector identities section (linked in the question).

Comment: How do you define $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial x^T}$? This might help you understand.

Comment: @PC1 I do not know how the double derivative must be defined. Trying to define it brings me back to my original question - 1. How is the derivative with respect to a row vector defined? (Is it even defined?) or 2. is the transpose in the double derivative representing a transpose action done so that the second derivative takes place on a column vector.

Comment: @sdnemina I don't understand your notation but the definition of your derivatives is critical. It should be clear from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus (the page you link in your original question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Too long for a comment.**

The usual mathematical definition of a derivative for $f:\mathbf{R}^p \to \mathbf{R}^q$ will yield $f'(x) = \left[ \dfrac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} \right]$ of dimensions $(q,p).$

In *statistics*, they often define, for $f:\mathbf{Mat}_{(p,q)} \to \mathbf{R},$ $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial X} = \left[ \dfrac{\partial f}{x_{ij}} \right],$ which is a matrix of dimensions $(p,q).$ When $q = 1,$ we have the matrices of dimension $(p,1)$ and these can be identified with column vectors which is the usual way to write vectors and, therefore, they identify with $\mathbf{R}^p.$ Then, the statistician believes for $f:\mathbf{R}^p \to \mathbf{R},$ $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is of dimension $(p,1)$ (a column vector). This clashes with the definition above. The clash is resolved by taking transposes. The statistician will also use "$\partial x^\intercal$" to mean "take the transpose of this matrix derivative." Thus, $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x^\intercal}$ will be of dimension $(1,p)$ and coincides with the standard definition in mathematics.

How to resolve the issue? Trace dimensions, that is it. Both definitions will yield the same numbers but arranged differently.

Why does the statistician do this? The main reason is that if $f,$ a real-valued function of the matrix $X,$ is differentiated and then the derivative evaluated in some "increment" $H = (h_{ij}),$ then we must get $\sum\limits_{i,j} h_{ij} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_{ij}}.$ It is just algebra to show that this is equal to
$$
\mathrm{tr} \left( H^\intercal \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial X} \right).
$$
This proves to be a very efficient way to represent the derivative of matrix functions and it resembles the gradient and dot product for the standard case. That is, if $f:\mathbf{R}^p \to \mathbf{R},$ then
$$
f'(x) \cdot h = \nabla f(x)^\intercal h
$$
(in fact, the two expressions coincide since the trace of a scalar is itself). The so-called "matrix calculus" is therefore developed ad-hoc to satisfy the statistician. Many of their formulas are concise and useful, albeit cumbersome to derive.