# Hessian: $\dfrac{\partial^2f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial\mathbf{x}\partial\mathbf{x}^\top}$ or $\dfrac{\partial^2f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial\mathbf{x}^2}$?

Tags: matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix

I come across two definitions for the Hessian matrix

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{H} = \dfrac{\partial^2f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial\mathbf{x}\partial\mathbf{x}^\top} \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{H} = \dfrac{\partial^2f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial\mathbf{x}^2} \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

I suppose both notations follow the denominator layout. On the one hand, I am used to (1), which matches what I [was expecting to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-vector_identities). On the other hand, I am unsure about what does the author exactly mean by $\partial\mathbf{x}^2$ in (2). Any help is welcome.

Comment: I guess they are the same thing. If you want to justify the notation, maybe see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation

Comment: what is a vector squared supposed to mean?

Comment: @lmaosome that is the point...

Comment: There is only one Hessian. But it is common to have different notations for the same thing. I usually write the Hessian as $\partial^2f$.

Comment: It is just notation. I have never seen a transpose in the denominator.

Comment: The transpose in the denominator is commonly used in statistics. The statistician defines $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ to have the same dimension as $x$ when $f$ is real-valued. Of course then, this clashes with the standard notation which would be to say that $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is of dimension $(n,m)$ for $f:\mathbf{R}^m \to \mathbf{R}^n$ (it clashes when $n = 1$). The statistician then defines $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x^\intercal}$ to mean the transpose of $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}.$ With these considerations, the Hessian should be written as in (1).

Comment: @WilliamM. Your concept of "standard" is clearly biased. Unfortunately, there is no standard when it comes to matrix Calculus notation. In Engineering (in Statistical Signal Processing filed, at least), we also use the convention used by statisticians (denominator layout), but there are many other authors that follow the numerator layout, which is what you said to be "standard".

Comment: Nevertheless, the problem of understanding $\partial\mathbf{x}^2$ remains.

Comment: Check this similar post where I gave a lengthier comment. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4737746/derivative-of-a-row-vector-with-respect-to-a-column-vector-derivative-with-resp/4740236#4740236

Comment: @WilliamM. Thank you for sharing the comment. Again, there is no standard notation. The more books from different areas we read, the more we see that there is no "usual". "The so-called 'matrix calculus' is therefore developed ad-hoc to satisfy the statistician.", some Engineers, Mathematicians, Physicists, etc might disagree in "to satisfy the statistician"

Comment: Well, notation is just preference, and results are often done to obtain nice formulas ad-hoc for a given notation. That truism can be controversial but it remains a fact.